# Discord JS clearTimeout not resetting the setTimeout

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, cleartimeout

I doesn't work as intended . If i skip the song or stop the queue , the timer goes on but it doesn't reset with clearTimeout

```
function play(guild, song) {

  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
  
   clearTimeout(timeoutID);
   timeoutID = null;
   var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();}, 10000);
   

   queue.delete(guild.id);
   return;

}
      options = {
  quality: 'highestaudio'
};


  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url), { quality: 'highestaudio'})
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(":musical_note: Started Playing: " + `**${song.title}**`);

}
```

Comment: you're accessing `timeoutID` before reference

Comment: i tried putting clearTimeout after timeoutID , but when i skip or stop a song again the timer doesn't go on again and the bot stays on server not disconnecting